# Javaws run with -javaagent on many JRE

Tags: java, javaagents

I want to run an agent on webStart application in many JRE. So far I can run only an app, the agent is not working. I run a bat file that I found it on stackoverflow::

```
@echo off

set JRE_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.6.0_14
set ARG=

set ARG=%ARG% -Xbootclasspath/a:"%JRE_HOME%\lib\javaws.jar";"%JRE_HOME%\lib\deploy.jar"
set ARG=%ARG% -classpath "%JRE_HOME%\lib\deploy.jar";"%JRE_HOME%\lib\javaws.jar";
set ARG=%ARG% -Djnlpx.home="%JRE_HOME%\bin"
set ARG=%ARG% -Djnlpx.slashport=-1
set ARG=%ARG% -Djnlpx.jvm="%JRE_HOME%\bin\javaw.exe"
set ARG=%ARG% -Djnlpx.remove=false

set ARG=%ARG% -Djava.security.policy=file:"%JRE_HOME%\lib\security\javaws.policy"
set ARG=%ARG% -DtrustProxy=true -Xverify:none -Djnlpx.heapsize=NULL,NULL

set WSARG=-J-javaagent:D:\simple-agent-1.0.8-jar-with-dependencies.jar=logging.password=1111;logging.item=Karta;main.class=pl.xxx.XXXApp

"%JRE_HOME%\bin\javaw.exe" %ARG% com.sun.javaws.Main %WSARG% D:\xxx.jnlp
```

The process starts but before the agent starts working the process restarts. After the process restart agent is not working.

Why process is restarting? Is there something I can do about it?